# How to Minify CSS with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

1. Install Node
2. Install NPM
3. Go to the project folder root in the file: `webpack.mix.js.`

   ```
   mix.styles([
      'public/css/vendor/normalize.css',
      'public/css/vendor/videojs.css'
   ], 'public/css/all.css');
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Mix automatically minifies your CSS when running

```
npm run production
```

[Laravel 5.7 Mix - Running Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#running-mix)